# Opening a pipe to a program and putting it into standard input

Tags: c++, pipe, exec, fork, execvp

so I'm trying exec a program given by a user, say ls on unix system. And save all of that into a string such that I can store it in a map.

My the program I need to call is Variables[key] (which is  map), which is the user submitted command, after which I want to save over it with the string created by it. This is code that I have tried to adapt to it, originally it was a redirection to a file, but having issues trying to use it with a string stream. Thanks in advance for any help <3

```
    string key = argv[1];

    int fds[2];
    int count;
    int fd;
    char c;
    pid_t pid;

    pipe(fds);


    if (fork() == 0)
    {

        dup2(fds[0], 0);


        close(fds[1]);

        stringstream ss;

        while ((count = read(0, &c, 1)) > 0)
        {
                ss << &c;
        }

        string temp;
        ss >> temp;
        cout << temp << endl;


        execlp("echo", "echo", NULL);


    }
    else if ((pid = fork()) == 0)
    {
        dup2(fds[1], 1);

        close(fds[0]);

        cout << argv[1] << argv << endl;

        execvp(argv[1], argv);
        perror("execvp failed");

    }
    else
    {
            waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
            close(fds[0]);
            close(fds[1]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
ss << &c;
```

Use this:

```
 ss << c;
```

What you do is to write a `char*` into your stream, which is assumed to be a null terminated string. However, it's just a char not a null terminated string, so what you are doing is undefined behaviour. Instead, you should just write the character to the stream.

Comment: Hmmm, before any of that though, I seem to have a problem with execvp. argv[1] is the name of the thing I want to run, but it isn't working?

Comment: Use `argv + 1` instead of `argv`. You probably want to cut the name of your program and execute the arguments instead.